# Почему сайт долго грузится после простоя?

Tags: lamp, linux

Доброго времени суток. Уже который раз натыкаюсь на проблему - сайт (что на PHP, что на NodeJS) после длительного простоя (без обращений хотя бы минут 10, а то и меньше) грузится в 5-20 раз медленнее. К примеру на nodeJS вместо 35мс - 450мс, на php5 вместо 35мс - 980мс. Сразу после этого в два раза быстрее, третий запрос - как и должен.

К архитектуре самих сайтов это никакого отношения не имеет (сам писал, кеш живёт далеко не 10 минут, а, как правило, 30 дней). К СУбД, возможно тоже - Nodejs-сайт использует mongodb, а все php сайты - mySQL. Соответственно, я делаю вывод, что это уже сама ОС как то оптимизирует свои расходы.

Вопрос: что это и как от этого избавиться\это отключить? На данный момент у меня одна VPS, на OpenVZ, с Ubuntu-server на борту.

Comment: Через 5 минут после написания этого вопроса поймал - <-- page generated 6.996 sec     -->.  Жму F5, <-- page generated 0.041 sec     -->. В общем - это жесть какая то =(

Comment: Поковыряйтесь в настройках Apache. Может быть, что управление процессами и потоками настроено корявенько. Вот [здесь](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mpm.html) о Multi-Processing Modules в Apache.

Comment: Честно говоря ничего не понимаю в этом. Апач стоит из коробки, + модуль для assignUserId. Команда из статьи выдаёт:root@faiwer:/etc/apache2# apache2 -lCompiled in modules:  core.c  mod_log_config.c  mod_logio.c  itk.c  http_core.c  mod_so.c

Answer (score 3):

Логируйте "медленные" запросы к базе (MySQL) в конфиге my.cnf добавьте примерно так

- ; логгируем запросы длиннее 5 секунд
- long_query_time = 10
- log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysqld-slow-query.log
- ; логгируем запросы, не использующие индексы
- log-queries-not-using-indexes

Потом внимательно изучаем логи

Comment: только перед тем как это делать, стоило бы локализовать проблему, запустив простейший скрипт php без mysql

Comment: Спасибо, прописал - проверю. Но сомневаюсь что дело в нём, ибо nodejs использует mongodb, и тоже подвержен этой проблеме (хоть и в меньшей мере), + тестируемый сайт на некоторых, подверженных глюку страницах, вообще не должен, поидее, делать SQL-запросы.